# Which load balancers to use when I have microservice architecture in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have UI in angular, backend in Rest api and few more services like license and authentication.
I am going to deploy them on different instances. I want my ui and backend to be load balanced and autoscale. 
My application is https so which load balancer should I use for UI and backend. I thought of using tcp(internal load balancer) for backend and https(external load balancer) for frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your use case, HTTPS LB for the front end makes the most sense since it can help with autoscaling and is better suited to handle HTTPS requests for your application.

a TCP Internal LB makes sense between your front end and your backend since you don't need to worry about application layer decisions at that point and really just need something to distribute the load.

Comment: As my application is in angular, all calls to authentication and licensing service will go from browser itself. If I use TCP load balancer my backend service as well as other services(auth and license) will be in VPC. On the top of that I am using https so I need to use all services by there hostname instade of IP. So my question is how my aithentication and licensing will get called from outside VPC (directly browser) by name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking then. Are you asking how you should configure the HTTPS LB? If so, please update your question. Otherwise, using a L7LB for the front end and a TCP ILB should suffice for communication between your front end app and the backend

Comment: @RujutaS - Your question is way too broad, there are 50 different ways to accomplish this. You are also confused about UI and front-end and back-end systems. Spend some time on your question and clarify exactly what your end goal is - with details. Then we can help you with ways to implement it.